# Phoenix TrustedCore password

Tags: bios, passwords, phoenix

I have a Five9 X2000 server with PhoenixTrusted Core on it. The user password is set (and known) but the supervisor password is "clear". When accessing BIOS it asks for a password (which, again, only the user is set). When I access BIOS I only have user privileges. I do not have access to certain areas of the BIOS (including being able to set an unset supervisor password in order to be able to delete the unwanted user password) When I change the user password to nothing it saves and says clear, however on reboot it asks for the password to enter BIOS again. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you should try something other then a blank password.

Comment: I'm not certain what you mean. BIOS requires a password. The only set password is the user password. I don't want there to be a password for the supervisor or user. Since the user is the only one that is set, I use that one to enter BIOS but it has limited permissions. A lot of options are greyed out. i thought if I were able to set a supervisor password that I could then delete the user password but the option is greyed out. If I change user password to nothing it clears and says it saves but it doesn't save. All I want is to delete the user password.

Comment: I mean that, your attempting to set the password to something, the firmware is likely rejecting but failing to notify you of.  Have you tried setting a password for the supervisor password, so you can at least, login as that and get access to all the options?

Comment: That's the thing though. I can't set a Supervisor password. When it askes for a password to enter BIOS I tried leaving it blank and hitting enter since supervisor is not set. Rejected. So I HAVE to enter a password which is the user password. Upon entering that password I enter BIOS and do not have the ability to even set a Supervisor password. It seems like the supervisor capability has been locked out by virtue of setting a user password without a supervisor password. Design oversight?

Comment: You have reset the device, and then tried, the default password which isn't "clear" right?

Comment: When I said the supervisor password was "clear" I just meant it was listed as clear in the BIOS and not "set" like the user, which has a password. Before user had a password it was listed as "clear" as well. After it was give a password it changed to "set". Sorry for the confusion. Essentially all I want to do is unset the stupid password but it seems as though once it is set, it cannot be returned to clear.

Comment: So I thought this was networking hardware, didn't know it was just server rack hardware with your typical UEFI firmware

Answer (score -1):

It is probably stored in EEPROM somewhere. If it is, it is a cleansing experience to spend all night typing in passwords. I once did that, and remembered my password a few years later :/ If it is in EEPROM, you will need proof of purchase when contacting support - works for Sony machines, at least. Also, try removing the CMOS battery for 30 minutes (and remove powercord), reinsert it, boot and check bios again.